# How do I resize a UINavigationController's contents when a UISplitViewController rotates to portrait

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController that uses a navigation controller for its master (left) pane. When it rotates to portrait, this navigation controller is represented within a UIPopoverController. I'm noticing that the UITableView that is being shown in the navigation controller's current view does not resize when the app rotates to portrait. Namely, I see the popover at full height (about 1024 pixels), but the table is black along the bottom, seemingly still about 700 pixels in height.

How do I adjust the navigation and/or table view height properly?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but for future reference, the documented way of handling this is to set the [contentSizeForViewInPopover](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/contentSizeForViewInPopover) property on the view controller. You can also use the popoverContentSize property of the popover controller. See the dev docs for details.